# Concatenating nested tuples

Tags: python, nested, tuples, concatenation

Given two variables

```
A = (2, 3)
B = (1, 4), (5, 8)
```

what is the simplest way to concatenate the two into a result variable `C`, so that:

```
C = ((2, 3), (1, 4), (5, 8))
```

Note that simply calling:

```
C = A + B
```

results in:

```
C = (2, 3, (1, 4), (5, 8))
```

which is **not** the desired result.

Further, note that tuples are preferred in the place of lists so that `A`, `B` and `C` can be used elsewhere as dictionary keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say that you probably meant the `A` tuple to be a nested tuple as well:

```
>>> A = ((2, 3),)
>>> A + ((1,4), (5,8))
((2, 3), (1, 4), (5, 8))
```

Comment: You'd be right about that one, though I inferred that from larsmans original answer (which he has now changed).  I guess I should give you the tick for being the first one to state it explicity?  Upboats to you both, though ...

Answer (score 6):

That's

```
(A,) + B
```

Note that `B` is already a nested tuple while `(A,)` constructs one from the flat tuple `A`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control consider using lists. If `A` is a nested tuple instead it would be easy enough to do this:

```
>>> A = (2, 3),
>>> B = (1, 4), (5, 8)
>>> A + B
((2, 3), (1, 4), (5, 8))
```

Comment: input is not `A = (2, 3),` it's `A = (2,3)`

Comment: I was trying to imply that `A`  should have been an nested tuple too but as everyone has got there answer in before me I didn't think it was worth going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `*` spready syntax:

```
C = (A, *B)
```

This will spread the nested tuples of `B` in the result, but `A` will be taken as is.

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help

```
>>> A = (2, 3)
>>> B = (4, 5)
>>> C = (A,) + B
>>> C
((2, 3), (1, 4), (5, 8))
```

Comment: This is correct, but it's basically the same as Fred Foo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
tuple1 = (1,2,3)
tuple2 = ('a', 'b','c')

nestedTuple = (tuple1,) + (tuple2,)
print(nestedTuple)
```